# How to make sure property gets mapped as observable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

So I have a ViewModel Like this:

```
public class ViewModel{
   // Constructors, other properties
   public List<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
   public ItemViewModel SelectedItem {get;set;}

   public void InitializeViewModel(){
       //Case 1:
       SelectedItem = null;
       //Case 2:
       SelectedItem = Item.FirstOrDefault();

   }
}
```

In my cshtml I have the following:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Model.ToJson()));
```

What I notice with this is that **ko.mapping.fromJS** binds *Case 1* as observable. However, when *Case 2* is set, ko.mapping.fromJS doesn't map SelectedItem as observable.

How can set up my code so that Case2 is implement and ko.mapping.fromJS maps the SelectedItem property?

Here is the breaking Code: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=33048714B5BF3B4B!1261

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, ko.mapping will map properties of ItemViewModel to observable but not ItemViewModel itself. If you want to make ItemViewModel get mapped you can define the mapping as:

```
var mapping = {
            'SelectedItem': {
                create: function (options) {
                    return ko.observable(options.data);
                }
            }
```

And call the js conversion:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Model.ToJson()), mapping);
```

Comment: var mapping = { 'SelectedItem' : { ...  did it. Thanks this is perfect.